# How to get(select) the rows with max value of a particular column using grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with duplicate data of books issued by students. 
Students can issue books(one book at a time in this case).
SQL for the table trn_books:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trn_books` (
  `tb_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tb_roll` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tb_isbn` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tb_date_issue` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tb_date_return` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `trn_books` (`tb_id`, `tb_roll`, `tb_isbn`, `tb_date_issue`, `tb_date_return`) VALUES
(1, 'L23', '1234441225', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-20'),
(2, 'L54', '1225565412', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-22'),
(3, 'L23', '1225565412', '2017-01-22', '2017-01-31'),
(4, 'L24', '1225565412', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-11'),
(5, 'L23', '1225565412', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-25');

ALTER TABLE `trn_books`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tb_id`);
```

Record storing in this way:
**Query: SELECT * FROM `trn_books`**

[image]

Now I want to track the last activity of students using grouping by their tb_roll. 
As we see that, the student with roll number L23 issued books three times where the last activity was:(according to max value of tb_date_return).
(5,L23,1225565412, 2017-02-15,2017-02-25). 
If I group by the table I am getting :

**Query: SELECT * FROM `trn_books` group by tb_roll**

[image]

But I need the result of the students' latest activity(max value of tb_date_return). 
Desire result should be tb_id's-->5,4,2.

But I am getting tb_id's->1,4,2 
How to achieve it by mysql query.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: provide SQL query

Comment: provide data as text table or as create / insert statements make a export from your data...  dont provide screenshots of PHPMyAdmin

Comment: You are grouping, so maybe you can use the MAX aggregate function. Anyway more context could be useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is normally accomplished using a `join` and `group by`:

```
select b.*
from trn_books b join
     (select tb_roll, max(tb_date_return) as max_tb_date_return
      from trn_books
      group by tb_roll
     ) b2
     on b2.tb_roll = b.tb_roll and
        b2.max_tb_date_return = b.tb_date_return;
```

Another common method is a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*
from trn_books b
where b.tb_date_return = (select max(b2.tb_date_return)
                          from trn_books b2
                          where b2.tb_roll = b.tb_roll
                         );
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the max date returned for any given tb_roll?

```
select tb_roll, max(tb_date_return) as max_return
from trn_books
group by tb_roll
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a max group wise problem.
You need to solve this with a delivered table.

**Query**

```
    SELECT
     trn_books.*
    FROM (
      SELECT
         tb_roll
       , MAX(tb_date_return) as max_return 
      FROM 
       trn_books
      GROUP BY
       tb_roll
      ORDER BY 
       tb_roll ASC
    )
     AS 
      tb_roll_max
    INNER JOIN 
      trn_books
    ON
       tb_roll_max.tb_roll = trn_books.tb_roll
     AND
       tb_roll_max.max_return = trn_books.tb_date_return
     ORDER BY 
       trn_books.tb_id DESC
```

**Result**

```
 tb_id  tb_roll  tb_isbn     tb_date_issue  tb_date_return  
------  -------  ----------  -------------  ----------------
     5  L23      1225565412  2017-02-15     2017-02-25      
     4  L24      1225565412  2017-02-01     2017-02-11      
     2  L54      1225565412  2017-01-12     2017-01-22
```